# How to Store MySQL Table in a PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to store all values in a table called `locations` from MySQL database which looks like

[image]

into a PHP Array called `$locations = array();` .I need to store the data in a format(Associated array or Regular) which I can convert them to a JSON file by using the php's `json_encode()` function. The final output must looks like

```
{
    "markers": [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "shelter",
        "lat": 55.6295639,
        "long": 12.6392556,
        "latlong": "55.6295639,12.6392556"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "shelter",
        "lat": 49.6125639,
        "long": 12.6392556,
        "latlong": "55.6295639,12.6392556"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "shelter",
        "lat": 56.6786339,
        "long": 11.6392556,
        "latlong": "55.6295639,12.6392556"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "type": "shelter",
        "lat": 51.6295639,
        "long": 13.6392556,
        "latlong": "55.6295639,12.6392556"
    }, ]
}
```

I already tried this code but not sure I am doing right? or how to export it to json?

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from locations');

$locations = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    $row = array();
    foreach($r as $k=>$v) {
         $row[$k] = $v;
    }
    array_push($locations,$row);
    unset($row);
}
```

Comment: 1. `var_dump($locations)` 2. `json_encode` 3. you don't need `unset` there 4. You don't need a loop - just `$locations[] = $r;`

Comment: Please no longer use mysql_* as it is deprecated and will be removed from PHP soon. Please switch over to using the mysqli set of functions/methods

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: what if there is 10Mb of legacy code that uses it already and that will never be upgraded to a never php version ever (unless it's rewritten)?

Comment: @zerkms Don't upgrade PHP, ever :)

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: right. So your advice should contain an explicit "for new projects" otherwise it looks not helpful.

Comment: @zerkms I'm being semi sarcastic. It wouldn't be the first time a project has to be semi refactored as a result of an API change, and it's not going to be the last (look at every time drupal gets upgraded). It's just part of the business. I work for the largest tech company in the world, and even they have to do it sometimes for thousands of projects due to security issues, strategic shifts, or necessary changes like this.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: there are no security issues with `mysql_` extension. Any issue is caused by wrong usage (lack of knowledge/experience). `mysqli`/`PDO` affected by the same issues. Using pdo/mysqli doesn't make your code protected automagically. The opposite is true as well: using `mysql_` extension doesn't make your code vulnerable either. "or necessary changes like this" --- if you don't have plans to migrate to the php that has dropped `mysql_` support - there is no practical reason to force migration.

Comment: last comment before I start loosing rep for being chatty: @zerkms Where are you getting security out of this? PHP upgrades include security enhancements, that's a big reason to update (same as your OS, or any other application). I have yet to mention anything regarding security with regards to the usage of the mysql_* api. I've only mentioned security in the context of major refactors, regardless of the item to be refactored.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: do you know any vulnerability for php 5.3.10 (the latest available in the latest ubuntu lts that still supports mysql_ ext) that can be exploited not by stupid code, but because it's a flawless in the php itself? Yeah, I know "we need to upgrade because of security" - would work for managers, but anything for tech people?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43222/discussion-between-zarazthuztra-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could just:

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from locations');
$locations = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    array_push($locations, $row);
} 

//echo json_encode($locations)
```

Comment: Hi Floris, Thanks for your hint, is there any way I can store the json file on the server? I mean by ecohing the data I am not able to grab them by Ajax ,so how I can save the result on a file?

Comment: yup

file_put_contents('locations.js',json_encode($locations));

Comment: PHP has `file_put_contents()`, a really easy way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

When you call mysql_fetch_array(), the row returned is already an associated array. What you can then do is store that row in another array (effectively now a two dimensional array), but you'll also want that array to be associative. If you follow Floris' method, you'll achieve your desired result just fine, so I'm just going to provide an alternative whereby each row gets some sort of meaningful label for your JSON export

NOTE: mysql_* functions are deprecated. I am only using them for the purpose of example. Please comment or send a message and I will post the mysqli version.

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from locations');
$locations = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $locations['location_'.$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($locations);
```

EDIT: The mysqli version using 1:1 function conversions and no security enhancements, or object oriented code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);//these can have defaults as per your php.ini file.

$result = mysqli_query('select * from locations');
$locations = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $locations['location_'.$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}    
echo json_encode($locations);
```

Comment: Thanks Zarazthuztra, Can you please let me know how to use the mysqli insteard of my code?

Comment: Sure! It's really not much different than mysql itself, I'll edit my answer. Although first, make sure you've followed the following guide for setup: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.setup.php

Comment: @zerkms, thanks for catching that error! I was typing up a post for something and totally zoned on that one.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it Behseini,

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from locations');

$locations = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $loc["id"] = $row["id"];
    $loc["type"] = $row["type"];
    $loc["lat"] = $row["lat"];
    $loc["long"] = $row["long"];
    $loc["latlong"] = $row["latlong"];

    array_push($locations,$loc);
}
```